# classlist.toggle() with force false still adding class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a side navigation bar with a button to toggle showing just the icons or to show the icons and the text. There are multiple different HTML pages that share this nav bar, so I needed to save the nav bar's state for when you switch to each (Dashboard to Items, Contacts to Dashboard, etc). I do this using the follow code:

```js
var navBar = document.querySelector(".side-bar");
var toggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");

window.onload = () =>
{
    let isClosed = localStorage.getItem("navState");
    navBar.classList.toggle("nav-is-closed", isClosed);
}

toggle.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
    let isClosed = navBar.classList.toggle("nav-is-closed");
    localStorage.setItem("navState", isClosed);
});
```

```css
.side-bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--default-back-color);
  min-width: 200px;
}

.nav-is-closed {
  min-width: inherit;
}

.nav-is-closed a h2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styles.css">

    <!--Google Fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Neucha&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Rucksack</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            <a href="#"><img src="resources/images/rucksack.png" alt=""></a>
            <h1 class="title">Rucksack</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="smaller-icon" href="#"><img src="resources/images/gear.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="resources/images/blue-profile.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="main-section">
            <nav class="side-bar">
                <a class="selected-nav" href="dashboard"><img src="resources/images/house-icon.png" alt=""><h2>Dashboard</h2></a>
                <a href="items"><img src="resources/images/item-icon.png" alt=""><h2>Items</h2></a>
                <hr class="nav-break">
                <a href="contacts"><img src="resources/images/contacts-icon.png" alt=""><h2>Contacts</h2></a>
                <hr class="nav-break">
                <a href="reports"><img src="resources/images/reports-icon.png" alt=""><h2>Reports</h2></a>

                <div class="nav-toggle"><img src="resources/images/arrow-icon.png" alt=""></div>
            </nav>
            <div class="content">
                <strong>Content</strong>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="shell-controls.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, except when you move to a new page while the nav is open. It closes even though in window.onload, isClosed is false. As far as I know, toggle with force set to false removes the class, but in this case it's still adding it.

[image: Open]
[image: Close]

Comment: Can you include your HTML code as well?

Comment: when you move to a new page, it should reload the page, make your problem happen, did you debug at `window.onload` ? And your approach is not the good idea, if you want to keep the nav, you should load only the different in content

Comment: @TannerDolby I edited my question and included the HTML. For now, all the other pages look identical. I have them separated into their own folders with an index.html file.

Comment: @RaphaëlVO I am loading a different page each time a nav link is clicked. I have multiple folders each with their own index.html. I debugged in the window.onload function, and that is where the problem lies. The problem is, when `isClosed=false` gets passed to `navBar.classList.toggle("nav-is-closed", isClosed);` The nav-is-closed class gets added, even though it shouldn't. Perhaps i'm missunderstanding how toggle works, but as far as I can tell, if force is set to false, it should not add the class.

As far as my approach being a bad idea, what is your reasoning behind that?

Comment: Have a look at the [DOMTokenList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) docs. It might clear up any issues your having.

Comment: @TannerDolby I have looked at the documentation, but it doesn't clear it up. This line in the documentation says "If set to false, then token will only be removed, but not added." That seems to suggest that what I'm doing is correct. However, even though force is set to false, it still adds the token. It says nothing about what happens if the token doesn't exist, and force is set to false. So, I assumed it would simply do nothing. Perhaps that's the wrong assumption.

Comment: Could there be somewhere in your code that the optional Boolean `force` parameter is returning true and therefore allowing the token to be added? My only explanation could be that `isClosed` is returning `true` at some point when localStorage *can* get the `navState` and that's what is causing the `force` parameter to be in true in the `.toggle()` invocation.

Comment: **Typo**: `isClosed` is a string, and even `"false"` is truthy for `toggleClass`. To never face this problem again, always `JSON.stringify` what you are about to save in the localStorage and `JSON.parse` what you retrieve from it.

Comment: @Kaiido Awesome, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Kaiido said, isClosed was being pulled from localStorage as a string, which caused toggleClass to think the string of "false" was truthy, therefore still adding the 'nav-is-closed' class. Adding JSON.parse when getting isClosed and adding JSON.stringify when setting isClosed in localStorage solves the problem.